# Perl: How can we check that which string is a sub string of another?

Tags: regex, string, perl, comparison, substring

I have 2 strings say A and B. Now any of these 2 can be a substring of another. For eg:

```
 Case:1-- A = "abcdef" and B = "abc" //String B is Substring of A.
```

or

```
Case:2-- A = "xyz" and B = "wxyza"  // String A is Substring of B.
```

Now I know about index function

```
 index($substr, $str)
```

but I don't know which one is a substring of another, so can't pass the parameters.

> I have done it using an `OR` where I check for both the cases by swapping the variables.

I only need to know that one of the strings is a substring of another.
**But I need a better technique to do so?** 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about checking the length of both strings before `index()`?

Comment: what if the length is same? say A ="abcd" B="bcef" then I wont be able to decide which one to pass as substring

Comment: What do you mean by "better technique?"  In one line, one statement, most efficient, most elegant ... ?

Comment: Obviously order doesn't matter if they are of same length.

Comment: You do need to know which one is contained (in the other one), yes?  That would be a complicated statement.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to know if there was a simpler method, say more precise than what I did, since I am a newbie in perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to submit the pair and get the string enclosing the other, or `undef`.

```
($enclosing) = grep { /$s2/ && /$s1/ } ($s1, $s2);
```

Here is a way to get the strings ordered as `($inside, $enclosing)`, or get an empty list

```
@sorted = sort { "$b$a" =~ /^$b.*$b/ <=> "$a$b" =~ /^$a.*$a/ }
          grep { $s1 =~ /$s2/ || $s2 =~ /$s1/ } ($s1, $s2);
```

This first filters out the no-match case by a two-way regex, passing through an empty list.

In both cases equal words aren't in any way marked as such, and I don't see how they could be. 

  However, they do contain each other and can probably be further processed the same way.

The only solution in this answer that delivers that is the `@mask` below, set to `(1,1)` in that case.

All code here runs under `use warnings` which is omitted for brevity.

---

Posted initially. Returns a copy of the word that is inside the other or `undef`.

```
($in) =  map { /^($s1).*$s1|(^$s2).*$s2/ ? $1 // $2 : () } ("$s1$s2", "$s2$s1");
```

Comments clarified that returning a code clasifying which string is inside the other may be useful.

```
($sc) =  map { /^($s1).*$s1|(^$s2).*$s2/ ? ($1 && 1) || ($2 && 2) : () } 
              ("$s1$s2", "$s2$s1");
```

The `$sc` is `1` when `$s1` is contained in `$s2`,or `2` when `$s2` is in `$s1`, or `undef` otherwise.

---

Depending on how this is meant to be used, the origin of the above may be useful

```
@mask =  map { /^($s1.*$s1)|(^$s2.*$s2)/ ? 1 : 0 } ("$s1$s2", "$s2$s1");
```

The `@mask` has `(bool, bool)` for whether words `($s1, $s2)` are inside the other.

It is: `(1,1)` (equal), or `(1,0)` or `(0,1)` (for `$s1` or `$s2` inside the other) or `(0,0)` (distinct).

Comment: okay so the mask contains 1,0 if s1 is a substring of the s2 right??

Comment: So my purpose is I need to check which one is the substr of the other. I can follow a convention like if the response is 0 first one is a substr of other and if response is 1 vice versa. But what you did helps!

Comment: No I would just add them in the map, and thats it. Thanks btw ;)

Answer (score 3):

> @zdim one statement

Knock yourself out,

```
print length($s1) > length($s2) 
  ? "s2 is @{[ index($s1,$s2) <0 && 'NOT ']}substr of s1"
  : "s1 is @{[ index($s2,$s1) <0 && 'NOT ']}substr of s2";
```

Comment: nice :)  That's _one_ statement? :+1

Comment: @zdim it could be. :)

Comment: @EugenKonkov perhaps not complete answer, as s1 is substr of s2, and s2 is substr of s1 at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that one of the string is a substring of the other, you could use something like:

```
my $c = ($sa =~ /$sb/) || (-1) *($sb =~ /$sa/);
```

Where 1 means $sb is a substr of $sa and -1 means $sa is a substr of $sb.